# Not able to locate an element by its string name

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2. I have to locate a dropdown element by using its sting name.So i have tried with below code,but its not working.

```
element(by.xpath("//content[contains(string(), 'Learn more')]")).click();
     or
element(by.xpath("//div[contains(string(), 'Learn more')]")).click();
```

The UI code is given below

```
<div jsname="YCbqLe">
    <div jsaction="aLn7Wb:kbDuhe">
        <div role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" class="Ej ljmwzf" jscontroller="YwHGTd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd(LgbsSe); keydown:I481le; keypress:Kr2w4b; mousedown:UX7yZ(LgbsSe),npT2md(preventDefault=true); mouseup:lbsD7e(LgbsSe); mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H(LgbsSe); touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(LgbsSe|preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd(LgbsSe); focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e;b5SvAb:TvD9Pc;" jsshadow="" jsname="HvyTdb" aria-label="Add a button (optional)">
           <div jsname="LgbsSe" role="presentation">
               <div class="EI" jsname="d9BH4c" role="presentation">
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb y3" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option">
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="BOOK" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option">
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="ORDER" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option">
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="SHOP" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option">
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb bf" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="LEARN_MORE" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" role="option">
                       <div class="qm he" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
                           <content class="u5 jh">
                                 "Learn more"
                           </content>
                   </div>
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="SIGN_UP" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option">
                   <div class="Di LMgvRb" jsname="wQNmvb" jsaction="" data-value="GET_OFFER" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" role="option">
                </div>
             </div>
```

How can i select the the drop down text "Learn more" here, using the text 'Learn more'.Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `text()` instead of `string()` gives the same (unwanted) result?

Comment: try `by.xpath("//content[contains(text(), 'Learn more')]")`

Comment: Are there always the same css classes?

Comment: I have tried with by.xpath("//content[contains(text(), 'Learn more')]"),but it tells element is not visible even the element is present in the UI.While using element(by.xpath("//content[contains(string(), 'Learn more')]")) , it tells another element is receiving the click.

Comment: I am able to click on that drop down button using element(by.css(".Xz2Gac .EI")).click(); But not able to click on that particular drop down element using that text name.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the css locator as below

`element(by.cssContainingText("content", "Learn more"))`

or with Xpath

`element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Learn more']")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But above code also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the text have some space. You can copy the complete text between tags and use that in that above xpath or can try the below example

```
//content[normalize-space(text())='Learn more']
```

or you can try this css

```
element(by.css("div[data-value="LEARN_MORE"] content")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath to locate the element. If click is not working out, probably this element does not have click action.

```
//content[contains(text(), '"Learn more"')]
```

You may try invoking the click action for either one of the below.

```
//div[@data-value="LEARN_MORE"]
```

or

```
//div[@data-value="LEARN_MORE"]/div
```